# How to merge and center two rows based on a column value in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a pandas dataframe which is as shown below.

```
ID       Lookup
A0001    Loc: File_location_A
A0001    IP: 10.0.0.1
A0001    Host: Human
B0001    Loc: File_location_B
B0001    IP: 10.0.0.2
B0001    Host: Cyborg
C0001    Loc: File_location_C
C0001    IP: 10.0.0.3
C0001    Host: Unknown
```

Expected output is

```
ID       Lookup
A0001    Loc: File_location_A
         IP: 10.0.0.1
         Host: Human
B0001    Loc: File_location_B
         IP: 10.0.0.2
         Host: Cyborg
C0001    Loc: File_location_C
         IP: 10.0.0.3
         Host: Unknown
```

The agenda is to write the above to a csv so as to replicate the merge and center behavior which we have in excel. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> The agenda is to write the above to a csv so as to replicate the merge and center behavior which we have in excel.

It is impossible, because `csv` has no formatting, so no possible set `merge` and `center` like in excel if run `df.set_index(['ID','Lookup']).to_excel('file.xlsx')`.

---

If need replace duplicted values to empty strings use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df.ID.duplicated(), 'ID'] = ''
print (df)
      ID                Lookup
0  A0001  Loc: File_location_A
1                 IP: 10.0.0.1
2                  Host: Human
3  B0001  Loc: File_location_B
4                 IP: 10.0.0.2
5                 Host: Cyborg
6  C0001  Loc: File_location_C
7                 IP: 10.0.0.3
8                Host: Unknown
```